# Sumif based on multiple criteria and location

Tags: excel, vba, formulas

I'm trying to use Excel to extract figures based on multiple criteria and their location within columns.

[image: My workbook]

So for example. If I wanted to do a `SUMIF` to receive the figures associated with the `First` class. The formula would retrieve the figure in a specified row,

But If I wanted to retrieve the figure associated with `England`. The formula would contain multiple criteria to look for the `First` class then look for the country `England` and retrieve the figure on its row in a specified column.

These columns will grow and shrink each month. Meaning I need it to be somewhat dynamic.

I've tried to do this using `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS` with no luck.

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D10,A2:A10,"First",B2:B10,"England")
```

Comment: could you have a situation where the data is not as regularly distributed over columns A, B and C like you have it represented? Could it be for instance that between rows 4 and 5 there would be an extra row with another value in the C column, so you would have "Spoon" in C4 and "Fork" in C5 (in the new row)?

Comment: Is the sum for *first* supposed to be **1** or **6**? Is the sum for *england* supposed to be **2** or **3**? Why not simply fill in the blanks and use a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B)?

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Comment: The sum for the first class would be 1. If would not sum the rows beneath it but get te value on the same row.

And yes. It is possible the data set could grow extra columns.

Comment: having a helper column with something like `=INDEX(A2:C2,1,SUM((LEN(A2:C2)>0)*COLUMN(A:C)))` (CSE+copy down) would be all you need... then simply SUMIFS with the helper column...

Comment: @Keva161, did you try any of the answers? Was there a solution? Could you come back to us and/or accept the answer that satisfies you?

Comment: Gotta love the Irish potatoe :-)

Answer (score 0):

The challenge you have is that in columns A, B and C, the values are not repeated downwards into the now blank cells. So values do not appear next to each other in the same row.

Assuming that the example you gave is quite simple, and you could also have multiple *International Products* for a given Class and Country, I would go for the following solution:

Reserve two columns (E and F) for intermediate calculations. If they are currently used, move those used columns to the right, making room for an empty E and F column. You could of course also choose two other columns for this purpose. But I will assume they are E and F.

Then in E2 put this formula and copy it further down the E column as far as needed.

```
=IF(A2<>"", A2, OFFSET(E2,-1,0))
```

In F2 put this formula and copy it down as well:

```
=IF(B2<>"", B2, IF(A2<>"", "", OFFSET(F2,-1,0)))
```

This should give the following display (the header titles in E1 and F1 are cosmetic only):

[image: [image]]

Now you can do formulas on those columns in combination with the C column. For instance:

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D10,   E2:E10,"First",   F2:F10,"England",    C2:C10,"")
```

And this would output 2. Note that if you really only want to match one row, you should specify a condition for each column (E, F and C).

The intermediate formulas in the E and F columns are quite resistant to deletion of rows, due to the use of `OFFSET`. If you insert rows, you should of course make sure the formulas in E and F are copied into it.

If you will ever use more than 3 columns for the source data, you'll need to also add more intermediate columns with similar formulas. Also your `SUMIFS` would need extra conditions then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following SUMPRODUCT() For Class and Country:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10=$F$1)*($B$3:$B$11=$G$1)*($D$3:$D$11))
```

Then for all three:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10=$F$1)*($B$3:$B$11=$G$1)*($C$4:$C$12=H1)*($D$4:$D$12))
```

A picture for references.

[image]

The idea is that each column must move down one row in its reference.  And the Sum column must start on the same row as the last column being referenced.